# OpenGL Zoom in / Zoom out with Mouse/Keyboard

Tags: java, opengl, awt, jogl

I am currently working on a project with both using awt and Java OpenGL. (separately)

Firstly, here is the related topic

[Adding Text to Screen with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208441/adding-text-to-screen-with-opengl)

I perfectly added zoom ability with using awt. I want to add zoom in/ zoom out ability(mouse position zoom or key, doesnt matter) to this program in OpenGL(JOGL) too. Currently, I can perfectly show degrees, add images and texts to anywhere I want, however couldn't figure out how to add zoom. I have gone through lots of web sites but couldn't even find useful-basic source code to study. Could you lead me to the right direction or at least share some sample code for the basics?

I use java.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always liked the NeHe tutorials, many different examples are available with source code in many programming languages. The tutorial is in C but the code can be downloaded in other languages and method names are very similar usually.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Regarding your zooming, try to translate your model coordinates into(closer to) the screen taking into account the point your zooming to (or from) (can be cursor location or just the center of the model). Another way might be to adjust the viewport but I recommend translating the model.